# Python 3 - Iterate through corpus and record its count

Tags: python-3.x

I have a corpus which is a list of tuple, with the tuple containing a word and a POS tag. My question right now is given every word and every POS tag that exists in the corpus, iterate through the corpus and record the amount of time each word and tag combo exist in the corpus. If the word and tag combo does not exist in the corpus make the count 0.

```
     possible_tags = ['Verb','Noun','Det']

     possible_words = ['Merger', 'proposed', 'Wards', 'protected', 'A']

     corpus = [('Merger', 'Noun'), ('proposed', 'Verb'), ('Wards', 'Noun'), ('protected', 'Verb'), ('A', 'Det'), ('Merger','Noun')]

     output = {'Merger_Noun':2, 'Merger_Verb':0, 'Merger_Det':0, 'proposed_Noun':0, 'proposed_Verb':1, 'proposed_Det':0, ....... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting everything to a dictionary to make it easier.

```
possible_tags = ['Verb','Noun','Det']

possible_words = ['Merger', 'proposed', 'Wards', 'protected', 'A']

corpus = [('Merger', 'Noun'), ('proposed', 'Verb'), ('Wards', 'Noun'), ('protected', 'Verb'), ('A', 'Det'), ('Merger','Noun')]

#Initialize output to empty dictionary
output = {}

//dictionary initialization.

for each_word in possible_words:
    for each_tag in possible_tags:
        key = each_word + "_" + each_tag
        output[key] = 0


#iterate through corpus
for each in corpus:
    #extract each tuple, and update dictionary with keys as string and count as integer
    output[each[0] +"_"+each[1]] += 1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but this solution doesn't solve all of my problems. The output from your solution only prints out word_tag combo that are in the corpus. I also want the word_tag combo that are not in the corpus and their count should be 0

Comment: You could just initialize empty dictionary with all possible combinations before doing this.

Comment: I have updated the code with initialization of empty dictionary. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I actually figured it out but thank you for your help.